# How to pass angularjs array data from asp.net webform to an angularjs function

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm a beginner with AngularJS and I'm trying to send data to an AngularJS controller from an asp.net webform.

More specifically, I have one or more rows of data in an Asp.net Web Form.  In each row I have 4 properties such as first name, last name, height, and weight.  What I'm trying to do is create an array in an AngularJS Controller and pass each row of data into the Controller and push it onto an array.  So I would have something like this:

Item(0).firstname
Item(0).lastname
Item(0).height
Item(0).weight

Item(1).firstname
Item(1).lastname
Item(1).height
Item(1).weight

etc.

So far I have this in my AngularJS controller:

```
// Item List Arrays
$scope.beneficiaries = [];

$scope.AddBeneficiary = function (b) 
{
   // Add a Item to the list
   $scope.beneficiaries.push({
      firstName:  b.firstName,
      lastName:  b.lastName,
      relationship:  b.relationship,
      percentage:  b.percentage
    });
}
```

And I'm trying to pass the data from my web form rows like this:

ng-model="benficiaries[0].firstName">

and then in the button I have

```
ng-click="AddBeneficiary(beneficiary[0])"
```

Obviously, this is not working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

The markup looks like this.  For example, for first name:

```
First Name:
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="uiBeneFirstName1" runat="server" MaxLength="20"  
CssClass="form-control" ng-disabled="model.uiBeneRelationship1 == '2'" 
TabIndex="35" ng-model="benficiaries[0].firstName"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

and the button click where I'm trying to pass the first firstname to the controller currently looks like this:

```
<button runat="server" ng-click="AddBeneficiary(beneficiary[0])">Add  Beneficiary</button>
```

Comment: From the provided code it looks like you're trying to add the first element of the `beneficiaries` array (which is nothing) to itself so nothing will happen. Show us your form markup

Comment: So the form markup would be something like this:<div class="col-sm-3 form-group ">  
                        First Name:
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="uiBeneFirstName1" runat="server" MaxLength="20"  CssClass="form-control" ng-disabled="model.uiBeneRelationship1 == '2'" TabIndex="35" ng-model="benficiaries[0].firstName"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.beneficiaries` is an empty array at the start so you cannot bind it to an input like

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="beneficiaries[0].firstName"/>
```

because there is no first element `$scope.beneficiaries[0]`. You need a different model in your form, example:

```
    <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="formData.firstName"/>
```

and your add button would have

```
ng-click="AddBeneficiary(formData)"
```